# Removing Duplicates from Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I m trying to remove duplicates from array of object using id, but id's are null then the object should contain those null id's and remove others which are duplicate

Here is the array of objects example:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 6652,
    value: "erger"
  },
  {

    id: 6652,
    value: "sdfs"
  },
  {

    id: 6653,
    value: "sdgdfg"
  },
  {

    id: 6000,
    value: "trgd"
  },
  {

    id: 6667,
    value: "asdf"
  },
  {

    id: 6667,
    value: "fdg"
  },
  {

    id: 6668,
    value: "dfgr"
  },
  {

    id: null,
    value: "fg"
  },
  {

    id: null,
    value: "dfgdf"
  },

  {

    id: null,
    value: "fg"
  },
  {

    id: null,
    value: "dfgdf"
  }
];
```

Below is the finalResult

```js
array = [{

    id: 6652
    value: "sdfs"
  },
  {

    id: 6653
    value: "sdgdfg"
  },
  {

    id: 6000
    value: "trgd"
  },
  {

    id: 6667
    value: "fdg"
  },
  {

    id: 6668
    value: "dfgr"
  },
  {

    id: null
    value: "fg"
  },
  {

    id: null
    value: "dfgdf"
  },

  {

    id: null
    value: "fg"
  },
  {

    id: null
    value: "dfgdf"
  }

]
```

In the above result the 6652 and 6667 is removed as they were duplicates and but null id are kept as i don't want to remove the null id and remove other repeated values.

Below is the logic i am trying to use but it doesn't work if ids are null

array=  array.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>( v.id !== null && t.id === v.id ))===i)

Comment: You're missing commas

Comment: You can use lodash to separate null, remove duplicate from remaining and then merge with null

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this out-

```js
const array = [{ id: 6652, value: 'erger' },{ id: 6652, value: 'sdfs' },{ id: 6653, value: 'sdgdfg' },{ id: 6000, value: 'trgd' },{ id: 6667, value: 'asdf' },{ id: 6667, value: 'fdg' },{ id: 6668, value: 'dfgr' },{ id: null, value: 'fg' },{ id: null, value: 'dfgdf' },{ id: null, value: 'fg' },{ id: null, value: 'dfgdf' },];
let index = 0;
const result = Object.values(
    array.reduce(
        (acc, curr) =>
            curr.id === null ? { ...acc, [index++]: curr } : { ...acc, [curr.id]: curr },
        {}
    )
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%; top: 0}
```

Comment: What exactly is this mess of an answer? Sorry, I'm not trying to be rude but this entire thing is a mess. I would *never* let this pass code review. First, there's no reason at all to use Object.values. You aren't using named variables. `a` and `c` are meaningless. There's extra destructuring happening in each iteration which is unnecessary. Overall this is very non-performant. Lastly, its incredibly difficult to parse out what this code is doing. Remember, you are *always* writing code for the next person to read.

Comment: @Geuis, Thank you for your response. I think you've missed the `reduce` method. The variables `a` and `c` means `accumulator` and `current` value and there is no destructuring. The `reduce` method generates an `object` so for getting the array of object the `Object.values()` is used. I hope you get the picture.

Comment: look at my answer below. You don't need to use Object.values at all. Single letter names for function arguments are never really acceptable. Variables should always be human readable (with the exception of things like for loops of course). Your answer may work, but its difficult to read and isn't very performant.

Comment: I've updated the variable from a single character to somehow meaningful names. I hope it makes you happy @Geuis :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const filterKeys = {};
const filtered = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.id === null || !(item.id in filterKeys)) {
    filterKeys[item.id] = true;
    acc.push(item);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Create a separate object to keep track of object ids that have been encountered, `filterKeys` in this case.

Since `array` is an array, do a reduce to iterate over the array. If the `id` is nuil or not found in `filterKeys`, push the item to the accumulator and return it for the next iteration. Since we don't care about ids that are null, they don't have an effect and are thus not filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code I tested(working) with your array of objects :

```
    arr.forEach(function (item) {

        if (item.id == null) {
            result.push(item);
        }
        else {
            var index = result.findIndex(x => x.id == item.id);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                result.push(item);
            }
           
        }
    });
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: This approach is inefficient. `result.findIndex` will potentially iterate over the entire array on each iteration. Its more efficient to store each new id as its encountered in an object (hash map, etc) and check if the new id was previously stored in the object.